# How can I send the output of a function generator to the STM board's ADC and check the digital values at the output?

Tags: stm32, adc, function-generator

I have an STM32F series board and I'm using the ADC. How can I send the output from a function generator to the board and get the digital output values on the STM32Cube IDE?

I'm using STM32cube IDE 1.7.0.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to write a firmware that instructs the ADC peripheral to do measurements (regularly, if you want that), you need to get the results of these measurements from the ADC registers (often, you'd want to use the DMA engine for that), and have the data over, often with some framing data you add, to some peripheral that communicates with your PC.

For all that, there's individual examples. Look through the examples!

Stm32F is sadly not a family, more like a whole kingdom of MCUs, so I can't know what communication peripherals your MCU has built in. It certainly has a UART, which you could connect to using a ttl-serial-to-USB converter. Most stm32 evaluation boards bring that functionality.

> output values on the STM32Cube IDE PS

Aside from debugging that firmware, the IDE will not inherently talk to your microcontroller! It's for writing the code for the Microcontroller.

To display the values on your PC, you'd attach a simple program that takes the bytes as your Microcontroller sends them from the USB adapter's emulated serial port and displays them in some human-readable form: as decimal numbers, or as graph, or however you want.